# JQL: query to find top level issue in current project

Tags: jira, jql

I have several projects and BLI in one project could be parent of BLI in another project.
How can I use JQL to find top level BLI within its own project?

Thanks,
Guoping

Comment: Can you give an example of top level BLI within its own project?

Comment: For example, I have two JIRA projects: parent_project and child_project. And in parent_project, I have a BLI called epic1. In child_project, I have a BLI called userstory1 and a child BLI called chid_task1. I only want to select out userstory1. Not child_task1. userstory1 is a top level BLI in child_project, although it has a parent epic1 in parent_project.

Answer (score 0):

A specific answer would require knowing your JIRA version (Cloud, Server, Data Center) and if the projects you are searching for are Software projects or Service Management projects.  This solution assumes you have Portfolio for Jira and the paid add-on Adaptavist Scriptrunner.

If your list of projects is not very long, then you could explicitly search by each project and use issuefunction.  This should work if you want any issue in one of these projects as long as it is not a subtask of another issue within its own project and regardless of whether it is linked to an epic or not:

```
(project = "child_project1" and issuefunction not in  subtasksOf( 'project in ("child_project1")' ) ) OR (project = "child_project2" and issuefunction not in  subtasksOf( 'project="child_project2"' ) ) OR (project = "child_project3" and issuefunction not in  subtasksOf( 'project="child_project3"' ) )
```

If you also need to include the epics from the other parent project, then add:

```
OR  issueFunction in epicsOf('Project = "parent_project1"')
```

Comment: I couldn't find both issueFunction and subtasksOf in my JIRA

Comment: Then you probably don't have Scriptrunner installed. Like mdoar's answer above, scriptrunner has the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A less elegant way which does not require using scriptrunner would be to filter by issue type.  You could filter for the issue types you want to select or filter out the issue types you don't want to select, assuming those two sets do not overlap in any particular project.  For example:

```
(project = "child_project1" and issuetype NOT in ( Sub-task, "Feature Defect")  ) OR (project = "child_project2" and issuetype  in  ( Story, Bug )  ) OR (project = "child_project3" and  issuetype  in  ( Story, Bug, Initiative )  )
```

To optionally include epics from parent project:

```
Or (project = "parent_project1" and issuetype  in ( Epic)  )
```

Comment: I know there's yet another way to do this as well, but it requires permission to use JIRA Structures.  If you have access to structures, you could take a look at the official documentation for that.  I don't have access so I can't help you myself.